# What went wrong with my curl install?

Tags: installation, updates, curl

I'm fresher than the prince to Linux, I've been following the instructions here: http://chrisfulstow.com/running-node-js-on-windows-with-virtualbox-and-ubuntu (the link tells what I am generally trying to do).

I'm all up and running in VBox, and am at the curl install part, I may have done the curl part a week ago I forget. So I ran this command anyway:

```
danjah@danjah-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install curl
```

Result:

```
[sudo] password for danjah: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
curl is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Then:

```
$ curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo npm_install=rc sh
```

Result:

```
fetching: {

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
/bin/tar: Child returned status 1
/bin/tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
It failed
```

Should I be concerned? How can I test curl? How can I avoid these situations? Perhaps there's a generic way of checking to see if I've already installed packages/etc?

Case specific answers and general advice most appreciated.

cheers, d

Comment: I doubt that anything went wrong with your curl install, the `fetching: {` message comes from the install script curl downloaded for you. In general, if you need to know if a package is installed: `dpkg-query -s curl` (or whatever package), and look at the line that starts with `Status:`

Answer (score 2):

What version of Ubuntu are you using? Because 11.10 (and 12.04) have node package manager in the repositories so it can be installed through the software centre or by

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

p.s. If you posted on [the forums](http://ubuntuforums.org) people would be able to walk you through exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply - Ubuntu 11.10, yes, and i have npm as I have installed 'connect', 'express' and 'yui3' via npm successfully. I ran the cmd provided anyway, and it has processed and installed npm (again?). No errors, until I try the 'curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo npm_install=rc sh'. You're right I should probably move this to ubuntu forums... I kind of like stackexchange though ;)